# How can I specify a specific rate to my test?

Tags: java, web-applications, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have a test plan with the following structure:

```
SimpleController  
      HTTP-Sampler-1  
      HTTP-Sampler-2  
      HTTP-Sampler-3  
      HTTP-Sampler-4  
      HTTP-Sampler-5  
      HTTP-Sampler-6  
      HTTP-Sampler-7
```

This `SimpleController` captures a "flow". Meaning that the samplers-1 through 7 is a "unit" meaning that after the `HTTP-Sampler-7` sends its request there will be a specific result in the server back-end.

I am interested in sending 30000 "requests" in total to the server. When I say "request" I mean all samplers under the controller.
But I want to start each request in every X seconds.

- I mean that a thread should send `HTTP-Sampler-1` every `X` seconds.

Taking into account that the recommendation is to use ~300 threads what is the configuration I should use to accomplish my test?

Comment: Does my post answer your question?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov:I will accept it as soon as I test this.+1 for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If those requests are the only one you want to execute, you can use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

Constant througput timer wants you to give it target throughput in samples per minute. As you have 7 requests per X seconds, you can set it to `7*60/X`. Also set Calculate Throughput based on to "this thread only"

Your test plan will be the same, only timer will be added to it.

If you also want to send other requests in this thread, I think you should use [Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Timer) or BSF.

Comment: But I don't want to send 7 requests/X seconds.I want to make sure that an `HTTP-Sampler-1` request is being send per X seconds

Comment: @Cratylus You will get it if you'll put timer after sampler 7

Comment: Put the timer with `7*60/X` you mean?

Comment: But how can I verify that the configuration meets the expectations?

Comment: @Cratylus what do you mean?

Comment: In this case you will get 7 requests per X seconds to be sent. If those 7 requests are the only one, you'll get what you want

Comment: So isn't there some reporting that shows the exact time to compare?

Comment: @Cratylus check e.g. [Transaction per Seconds](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond) or other listners from Jmeter plugins